# static node.js error by using xampp

Tags: php, html, node.js, netbeans, xampp

I recently started with p2p mediastreaming and used the tutorials of html5rocks.com for starting with webrtc https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab. I got it all working and it al worked fine for me.

The problem starts when I want to use it in a php project. I use netbeans as my IDE and xampp for running the code on my localhost. When I create a normal HTML5 application based on node.js, as descriped in step 6 of the tutorial, in netbeans and run the code with xampp on my localhost it works great. But when I copy the files to a php project and want to start my server.js by using the node.js command-line I get an error on the node-static. This doesn't happen in my html5 application.

C:\xampp\htdocs\eviltestmap>node servertje.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-static'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\eviltestmap\servertje.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

The path to my phpproject and the html5 application are diffent but the path I typ in the command-line is correct. I checked that multiple times.

Doe anyone know what could cause this error and how I can fix this?

Comment: If your modules aren't installed globally then you need to move them or reinstall them. `npm install node-static`.

Comment: THANK YOU! YOU ARE MY HERO OF THE DAY! It appears that I installed it in c:\users\documents with the npm install node-static. I should have installed it in c:\ to get in working in other folders as well.

Comment: If your paths are setup properly, you can use `npm install -g module-name` to install them globally. Node.js should then be able to find the path to the module.